# Accessing Functions of Model on view(phtml) page in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, model

I have a model called frontview.php and i want to access functions of the frontview.php models on the phtml file let say redub.phtml. can we do this? . Please Suggest.

Thanks In Advance!!

Comment: As always `$model = new Application_Model_Frontview(); $model->somefunction()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as Volvox suggested,you can use the same model functions in view script(phtml file) as you use them in any controllers

```
$model = new Application_Model_Frontview();
$return = $model->fetchAll();
```

now you can use $return in a foreach loop..

same as controller. hope this helps..